# Unable to get success with post request from java, but able to get success with postman

Tags: java, http-post, httpurlconnection

**Java Code:**

```
public class KeyGeneration {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Send Http POST request");
        sendPost();
    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private static void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes/changedneww741";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MTY3MjE4MDgsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiSmltIiwib3JnTmFtZSI6Im9yZzEiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTY2ODU4MDh9.8iUCGNaLYhC6MFPfnvc9lxk9b9Oi-5OtwLYgF7Pn6a8");


        String urlParameters = "peers=[\"localhost:7051\",\"localhost:8051\"]&fcn=move&args=[\"publickey\",\"raj1242\"]";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

**Error:**

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes/changedneww741    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
>     at mailsend.KeyGeneration.sendPost(KeyGeneration.java:131)  at
>   mailsend.KeyGeneration.main(KeyGeneration.java:35) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes/changedneww741    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
>     at mailsend.KeyGeneration.sendPost(KeyGeneration.java:125)  ... 1
>   more

Comment: you don't show the service you are calling, or it's configuration, or the postman request that succeeds. do you understand that makes it a bit hard for us to find the difference? Either way: response code translates into "BAD REQUEST", so there's something wrong with your request.

Comment: the `urlParameters` is not valid JSON

Comment: Yes I have passed valid JSON. Now it's working                                                     String urlParameters = "{\"peers\":[\"localhost:7051\",\"localhost:8051\"],\"fcn\": \"move\",\"args\": [\"publickey\",\"raj1242\"]}";